# SharePoint authentication issue when I try to connect sharepoint api from nodejs

Tags: api, authentication, sharepoint

```
const { headers } = await  spauth.getAuth(url, { username: "xyz", password: "xyz",
        relyingParty: 'urn:sharepoint:portal',
        adfsUrl: 'https://adfs3'
      })

headers = {
      ...headers,
      Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
}
```

Comment: this is the error 
 
  </S:Reason>
  <S:Detail>
    <psf:error xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
      <psf:value>0x80048823</psf:value>
      <psf:internalerror>
        <psf:code>0x80048823</psf:code>
        <psf:text>AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.</psf:text>
      </psf:internalerror>

Comment: Please add the error to your original question (by editing it) !

Comment: Or you could try to google the error message, i.e. "AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance" :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, the error `AADSTS53003`   means：

> BlockedByConditionalAccess - Access has been blocked by Conditional
> Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.

According to the document: [Troubleshooting sign-in problems with Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/troubleshoot-conditional-access), Administrators may have some conditional access policies set. Please refer to the above documents to make sure that you meet the conditions and avoid being blocked.